# bash script for loop variable control

Tags: linux, bash

I have this bash code live in file: garuns_opt_my.scr

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -S /bin/bash
#PBS -N garunsmodel
#PBS -l mem=2g
#PBS -l walltime=1:00:00
#PBS -e error/error.txt
#PBS -o error/output.txt
#PBS -A improveherds_my
#PBS -m ae

set -x


nodeDir=`mktemp -d /tmp/phuong.XXXXX`
cp -r /group/dairy/phuongho/garuns $nodeDir
cp /group/dairy/phuongho/jo/parity1/my/simplex.bin $nodeDir/garuns/simplex.bin
cp /group/dairy/phuongho/jo/parity1/nttp.txt $nodeDir/garuns/my.txt
cp /group/dairy/phuongho/jo/parity1/delay_input.txt $nodeDir/garuns/delay_input.txt

cd $nodeDir/garuns

module load gcc vle

XXX=`pwd`

sed -i "s|/group/dairy/phuongho/garuns/out|$XXX/out/|" exp/garuns.vpz

awk 'NR == 1 || $8=="'$c'" my.txt > simplex-observed.txt
awk 'NR == 1 || $7=="'$c'" {print $6}' delay_input.txt > afm_param.txt
cp "/group/dairy/phuongho/garuns_param.txt" "$nodeDir/garuns/garuns_param.txt"

./simplex.bin


awk 'NR >1' < simplex-optimum-output.csv>> /group/dairy/phuongho/jo/parity1/my/finalresuls${c}.csv
cp simplex-all-output.csv "/group/dairy/phuongho/jo/parity1/my/simplex-all-output${c}.csv"
#awk '$28==1{print $1, $12,$26,$28,c}' c=$c out/exp_tempfile.csv > /group/dairy/phuongho/jo/parity1/my/simulated_my${c}.csv
cp /out/exp_tempfile.csv /group/dairy/phuongho/jo/parity1/my/exp_tempfile${c}.csv

rm simplex-observed.txt
rm garuns_param.txt
```

What I am trying is to qsub the above bash script 'n" time using an external for loop lived in run.sh

```
for rep in {1..2};
 do qsub -V c=$rep garuns_opt_my.scr;
 sleep 7m;
done
```

Both garuns_opt_my.scr and run.sh are placed in the same directory.
However, I received the following error: qsub: script file 'c=1' cannot be loaded - No such file or directory.
Can you please help me to figure out what is the problem. 
Also, I am not sure the way I pass variable rep from run.sh to garuns_opt_my.scr is correct.
Thanks

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- a question should have the smallest amount of code which will allow someone else to reproduce the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The right usage of the `qsub` command should be:

```
qsub -V -c c=$rep garuns_opt_my.scr
```

According to qsub [man pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/qsub.1posix.html):

> ```
>    -c  interval
>           Define  whether the batch job should be checkpointed, and if so,
>           how often.
>
>    The qsub utility shall accept a value for the interval  option-argument
>    that is one of the following:
>
>    n
>           No   checkpointing   shall   be   performed  on  the  batch  job
>           (NO_CHECKPOINT).
>
>    s
>           Checkpointing shall be performed only when the batch  server  is
>           shut down (CHECKPOINT_AT_SHUTDOWN).
>
>    c
>           Automatic  periodic  checkpointing  shall  be  performed  at the
>           Minimum_Cpu_Interval attribute of the batch queue, in  units  of
>           CPU minutes (CHECKPOINT_AT_MIN_CPU_INTERVAL).
>
>    c=minutes
>           Automatic   periodic  checkpointing  shall  be  performed  every
>           minutes of CPU  time,  or  every  Minimum_Cpu_Interval  minutes,
>           whichever  is greater. The minutes argument shall conform to the
>           syntax for unsigned integers and shall be greater than zero.
> ```